# Load references with a specific orderby in ServiceStack Ormlite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Given the following set of classes:

```
public class Player 
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<Stats> Stats { get; set; }
}

public class Stats
{
    int Id { get; set; } 

    int PlayerId { get; set; } 

    int Year { get; set; } 
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to load the references such that they are ordered by the **Year**?

```
var result = Db.LoadSingleById<Player>(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to change how they're loaded from the DB, so you'll just have to sort them in code, e.g:

```
var player = Db.LoadSingleById<Player>(1);
player.Stats.Sort((x,y) => x.Year.CompareTo(y.Year));
```

Comment: @labilbe there's no provision to be able to do it, but what's an intuitive API for this query?

Comment: difficult indeed. Maybe something based on OrderBy instead of Sort.

Comment: @labilbe After `db.Load*` returns a concrete List, it's up to however you want to sort it in C#.